# How to exit setup installation before it completes?

Tags: visual-studio, installshield-le

I have made a setup project using installshield Limited Edition .What I need to do is to exit the setup process at a specific time during installation ..
I had this idea of creating a custom action which doesn't reach a specific path and generates an error which eventually exits the setup installation...but i dont want to display this error I  want to hide it and exit the setup ..tell me if you have any suggestions?